# Permission error handling in Google AutoML nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-automl, automl

[Permissions error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNuPU.png)

I'm currently experiencing an issue with authenticating the new Google AutoML API despite setting up the correct service accounts and attaching them as A JSON file inside the project.

Has anyone else had this issue? If so how did you go about resolving?

I'm using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/automl#installing-the-client-library

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the environmental variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to your credentials JSON file? When you get this error, it usually means some other credentials info (like your default credentials) are being passed instead. Check in your node code that that environmental variable is pointing to the right json file.